# PHPMyAdmin - Replace various items in text

Tags: regex, search, phpmyadmin

I need to do a search and replace in a database. The field is a text string consisting of various items separated by a `comma`.
I managed to do the search of various of this items using this:

> SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field1` = condition1 AND `field2` LIKE
>   'condition2' AND `field3` REGEXP 'item07 | item10 | item15 | item22 |
>   item30 | item36'

The result I get is the table row that matches condition1 and condition2. I would need something that selects and allows me to replace the **items in the text field**. I would replace them by nothing, since I want to delete them, so if there is any option that allows me to mass delete different items, that would work too.

I'm not an expert by any means, so I'm not even sure if there's a remote possibility to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE field1 = condition1 AND field2 LIKE 'condition2' AND field3 REGEXP 'item07 | item10 | item15 | item22 | item30 | item36'
```

Comment: No, I tried that already, and that will delete the row that matches the conditions, not the items in the text field.

Comment: I managed to solve it by using Notepad++. Thanks for your help :)